# Defining Hive external table on top of HBase existing table

Tags: hive, hbase, hcatalog

There is an empty **HBase** table with two column families:

```
create 'emp', 'personal_data', 'professional_data'
```

Now I am trying to map a **Hive** external table to it, which would naturally have some columns:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE emp(id int, city string, name string, occupation string, salary int) 
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":id,
                       personal_data:city,
                       personal_data:name,
                       professional_data:occupation,
                       professional_data:salary")
TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name" = "emp", "hbase.mapred.output.outputtable" = "emp");
```

Now the error that I get is this:

> FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   MetaException(message:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseSerDe: columns has 5 elements while
>   hbase.columns.mapping has 6 elements (counting the key if implicit))

Could you please help me out? Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your mapping, you're referencing the `id` field but you should reference the HBase `key` keyword. As stated in the [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HBaseIntegration#HBaseIntegration-ColumnMapping) :

> a mapping entry must be either :key or of the form
>   column-family-name:[column-name][#(binary|string)

Just replace `:id` by `:key` and that should do it :

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE emp(id int, city string, name string, occupation string, salary int) 
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,
                   personal_data:city,
                   personal_data:name,
                   professional_data:occupation,
                   professional_data:salary")
TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name" = "emp", "hbase.mapred.output.outputtable" = "emp");
```

The column mapping is based on the ordering of the columns, not on their names. In the documentation, paragraph *Multiple Columns and Families* you can clearly see that the names don't matter

```
CREATE TABLE hbase_table_1(key int, value1 string, value2 int, value3 int) 
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  "hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,a:b,a:c,d:e"
)
```

The mapping is then

- key -> id
- a:b -> value1
- a:c -> value2
- d:e -> value3

Comment: But would it then map Hive id column to Hbase key? Or am i getting something wrong? Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: Yes i re-read that bit of the documentation a several times and it confused me very much. Thank you very much cheseaux! It works perfectly. Have a good day.